# "The value is not a function and cannot be applied." error in F#

Tags: .net, f#, fparsec

I was trying to run the following `FParsec` code, until by some reason it stopped working:

[image]

The error I am getting is

```
"The value is not a function and cannot be applied."
```

If I comment out the last line of code (`test ns ".."`) it will not yield an error, though. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

---

The source code in text form is the following:

```
open System
open FParsec

let test p str =
    match run p str with
    | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg

type Namespace = { Name : string; Classes : string list; }

let classes : Parser<string list, unit> = 
  many (spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter .>> spaces)

let ns =
  pipe2 
    (spaces >>. skipString "namespace" >>. spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter)
    (spaces >>. skipString "{" >>. classes .>> skipString "}")
    (fun name classes -> { Name = name; Classes = classes } )

test ns "namespace abc { def ghi }"
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my VS editor and it ran just fine without any errors...

Comment: I am starting to think it may have something to do with some setting of my VS installation. I am getting strange errors in very simple F# files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noone could have **guessed** the answer here. The problem lied with other thing that I had decided to exclude from the post: the very header of my file:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
    #r @"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\fparsec-main-default\Build\VS10\bin\Debug\FParsecCS.dll";
    #r @"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\fparsec-main-default\Build\VS10\bin\Debug\FParsec.dll";
#endif
```

Replacing the `;` by `;;` will make all errors disappear:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
    #r @"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\fparsec-main-default\Build\VS10\bin\Debug\FParsecCS.dll";;
    #r @"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\fparsec-main-default\Build\VS10\bin\Debug\FParsec.dll";;
#endif
```

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't need any semicolons or double-semicolons in the (default) lightweight mode. Just `#r @"...."` should be fine.

Comment: Taking the ;; off will again give all the errors described in this thread!

Comment: The issue is indentation of the `#r` I think.  Don't indent them.

Comment: @brian: you seem to be right. What is the rationale behind this behaviour, though?

Comment: Well, I am surprised you don't get a squiggle on the first `open` after the indented `#r`.  But when the first line of code (after `#if` pre-processing) is indented, then the whole 'top level' for the file expects that level of indentation, and it throws off the whole whitespace processing of the file.  I am rather surprised that the code (with the last line commented out) compiles without error, as it seems to already be an indentation bug.  It appears that the F# 'lexfilter' that handles whitespace-processing may have some inconsistent behavior with regard to `#r`s.

Answer (score -1):

The red underlines clearly show that the compiler thinks that `pipe2` is taking four arguments--you should be able to confirm this by added parentheses around the entire test expression like so: `(test ns "namespace abs { def ghi })`

I'm not sure why though; try putting parentheses around the pipe2 call:

```
let ns = 
  (pipe2  
     (spaces >>. skipString "namespace" >>. spaces >>. many1Satisfy isLetter) 
     (spaces >>. skipString "{" >>. classes .>> skipString "}") 
     (fun name classes -> { Name = name; Classes = classes } ))
```

Comment: Both your suggestions are of no help. I don't believe the compiler thinks pipe2 is taking 4 arguments.

Comment: Defining a let *ns' = pfloat* will be ok until I go and add a *test ns' ""* which will again raise the same error as shown above.